# Einstein's Puzzle with 5 furniture customers

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Einstein had made quite a good zebra puzzle tough enough to confuse many people's brains. Today I present even tougher one, will you be able to solve it?

There are 5 customers, who bought a different set of furniture, each with different prices. Every customer wore a different coloured shirt and they all had different ages. The furniture was also delivered to their homes in different number of days. Right now all the customers are standing in a line.

**Names**: Barbara, Dana, Gina, Lori, Patricia.
**Furniture**: Cupboard, Desk, Dresser, Table, Wardrobe.
**Price**: 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200 (in dollars).
**Colour of Shirt**: Blue, Green, Orange, Red, Yellow.
**Delivery Time**: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 (in days).
**Age**: 40, 45, 50, 55, 60 (in years) .

**Clues** :

i) The customer whose delivery time is 25 days is somewhere between the customer whose delivery time is 20 days and the customer whose delivery time is 10 days, in that order.

ii) Lori is next to the youngest woman.

iii) At the fourth position is the 45 years old customer.

iv) The customer who bought the most expensive piece of furniture is next to the customer whose delivery will take 5 days.

v) The woman wearing the Yellow shirt is somewhere between the woman who bought the $900 piece of furniture and the 40-year-old woman, in that order.

vi) The customer who purchased the $900 piece of furniture is next to the customer whose delivery time is 20 days.

vii) The woman wearing the Green shirt is somewhere between the woman who bought the Table and the woman wearing the Red shirt, in that order.

viii) The woman wearing the Orange shirt is somewhere to the right of the woman wearing the Red shirt.

ix) Dana is somewhere between the customer who bought the Wardrobe and Lori, in that order.

x) The woman wearing the Green shirt is exactly to the left of the woman whose delivery time is 10 days.

xi) Barbara is next to the customer who bought the Wardrobe.

xii) The woman whose delivery time is 25 days is somewhere between the woman wearing the Yellow shirt and the woman whose delivery time is 5 days, in that order.

xiii) The 40 years old customer is next to the customer who purchased the $1100 furniture.

xiv) At the first position is the woman who bought the Table.

xv) The customer who purchased the 1100 dollars piece of furniture is next to the customer who purchased the 800 dollars piece of furniture.

xvi) The Cupboard was bought by the customer that is somewhere between Barbara and the 45 years old customer, in that order.

xvii) The 40-year-old woman is next to the 45-year-old woman.

xviii) The oldest customer is wearing the Yellow shirt.

xix) Patricia is somewhere between the woman who bought the $900 piece of furniture and the woman whose delivery will take 25 days, in that order.

xx) The customer that purchased the Dresser is next to the customer wearing the Green shirt.

xxi) The 50-year-old woman is next to the woman wearing the Yellow shirt.

Your job is to tell what each customers are, what furniture they bought at what price, what shirt colour they are wearing, what their ages are, at what time their furniture was delivered, and their  respective positions in the line.

Can you solve this puzzle? Note that this will take time, and you have to use every clue to solve this.

Good Luck!

Comment: FWIW, here is the [online solver I used](http://jsingler.de/apps/logikloeser/?language=en#(at:s,items:!(!(Barbara,Dana,Gina,Lori,Patricia),!(Cupboard,Desk,Dresser,Table,Wardrobe),!('800','900','1000','1100','1200'),!(Blue,Green,Orange,Red,Yellow),!('5','10','15','20','25'),!('40','45','50','55','60'),!('1/Left','2/Center-L','3/Center','4/Center-R','5/Right')),ms:t,n:!(),nc:7,ni:5,p:!(),v:0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer to this nice and entertaining puzzle:

> ```
>  Name     Purchase Price Shirt  Days Age Position
>
>  Barbara  Table     900  Blue    15  50  1/Left
>  Dana     Cupboard  800  Green   25  40  3/Center
>  Gina     Desk     1000  Orange   5  55  5/Right
>  Lori     Dresser  1200  Red     10  45  4/Center-Right
>  Patricia Wardrobe 1100  Yellow  20  60  2/Center-Left
> ```

Here is the [solved grid](http://jsingler.de/apps/logikloeser/?language=en#(at:s,items:!(!(Barbara,Dana,Gina,Lori,Patricia),!(Cupboard,Desk,Dresser,Table,Wardrobe),!(%27800%27,%27900%27,%271000%27,%271100%27,%271200%27),!(Blue,Green,Orange,Red,Yellow),!(%275%27,%2710%27,%2715%27,%2720%27,%2725%27),!(%2740%27,%2745%27,%2750%27,%2755%27,%2760%27),!(%271/Left%27,%272/Center-L%27,%273/Center%27,%274/Center-R%27,%275/Right%27)),ms:t,n:!(e4g0,e4g4,e3g3,e3g4,e1g0,e1g1,a3f0,c4g4,d4g0,d4g4,c1g3,c1g4,f0g0,f0g1,c1e3,d1g0,d1g4,b3g3,b3g4,d3g0,d3g1,b3d1,b3d3,c1d4,c1f0,d4f0,d4g3,d4e4,d4e0,e0g0,e0g1,e4g1,e0g2,a0b4,e1g2,d2g0,d3g4,a1g0,a1g4,a1b4,a3b4,b4g3,b4g4,a3g0,a3g1,a0g4,c3f0,c3g0,c3g2,c3g4,c0g1,c0g3,a0f1,a0b0,b0f1,b0g4,a4c1,a4e4,c1e4,a4g4,b2d1,f2g4,c4g1,c4e0),nc:7,ni:5,p:!(f1g3,b3g0,d4f4,a4g1,a3g3,d3g3,d1g2,e1g3,b2g3,c4g3,f0g2,c0g2),v:0)) on the jsingler online solver. Black plus and minus signs are directly issued from the hints in the OP, grey one are automatically deduced from them, as in every logic grid.

Comment: Great, you solved it correctly. Any more information you can give, like a logical path or something? I know it will be lengthy though.

Comment: Sorry but detailing every step, going back and forth through the 21 hints is really too time-consuming. I have added the solved grid to the answer but I have no time to add more. Solving this puzzle is rewarding enough for me and I will gladly leave the check mark to anyone who is brave enough to write everything down :-)